# Ubuntu 12.04, NUMLOCK not working

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, bios, numlock

I have a installation of Ubuntu 12.04, my NUM LOCK is disabled every time at boot, so i have to turn it on manually each time for the log in screen "password"

I tried these lines:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install numlockx
sudo sed -i 's|^exit 0.*$|# Numlock enable\n[ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ] \&\& numlockx on\n\nexit 0|' /etc/rc.local
```

and i edited in the file:

```
/etc/kbd/config, uncommenting lines:
Turn on numlock by default
LEDS=+num
```

and also:

```
Miscellaneous compatibility options, Enable Default Numeric Keys.
```

nothing works :(

i have windows 7 on the same machine, and num lock is okay, i guess it is not a bios problem!!

any help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This worked for me :) 

Ensure that numlockx is installed: 

sudo apt-get install numlockx 

Edit the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf 

gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

Add the following line to the file: 
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on

Comment: Put this as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

*From a comment of the OP:*

---

This worked for me:

Ensure that numlockx is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
```

Edit the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
 gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following line to the file:

```
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```